# How to calculate the accuracy of classes from a 7x7 confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, confusion-matrix

So I've got the following results from Naïves Bayes classification on my data set:

[image]

I am stuck however on understanding how to interpret the data. I am wanting to **find and compare** the accuracy of each class (a-g).

I know accuracy is found using this formula:

[image]

However, lets take the class a. If I take the number of correctly classified instances - **313** - and divide it by the total number of 'a' (4953) from the row a, this gives ~6.32%. Would this be the accuracy?

**EDIT:** if we use the column instead of the row, we get `313/1199` which gives ~26.1% which seems a more reasonable number.

**EDIT 2:** I have done a calculation of the accuracy of `a` in excel which gives me 84% as the accuracy, using the accuracy calculation shown above:

[image]

This doesn't seem right, as the overall accuracy of classification successfully is ~24%

Answer (score 1):

No -- all you've calculated is `tp/(tp+fn)`, the total correct identifications of class `a`, divided by the total of actual `a` examples.  This is *recall*, not *accuracy*.  You need to include the other two figures.

`fp` is the rest of the `a` column; `tn` is all of the other figures in the non-`a` rows and columns, the 6x6 sub-matrix.  This will reduce all 35K+ trials to a 2x2 matrix with labels `a` and `not a`, the 2x2 confusion matrix with which you're already familiar.

Yes, you get to repeat that reduction for each of the seven features.  I recommend doing it programmatically.

---

**RESPONSE TO OP UPDATE**

Your *accuracy* *is* that high: you have a *huge* quantity of true negatives, not-a samples that were properly classified as not-a.

Perhaps it doesn't feel right because our experience focuses more on the class in question.  There are [other statistics that handle that focus.

- *Recall* is `tp / (tp+fn)` -- of all items actually in class `a`, what percentage did we properly identify?  This is the 6.32% figure.
- *Precision* is `tp / (tp + fp)` -- of all items identified as class `a`, what percentage were actually in that class.  This is the 26.1% figure you calculated.

Comment: How would I go about doing this programmatically?

Comment: You sum the appropriate row and column slices from the 7x7 confusion matrix.

Comment: How are you operating Weka at the moment? If you're running it manually in the Explorer interface, right-click the result in the result list and choose **Save result buffer**, then import the file as a space-delimited file into a spreadsheet program where you can do the calculation.

Comment: How would I go about automating the calculations for all the classes `a-g` in excel? I've copied the confusion matrix into the columns

Comment: (1) This is a separate question; (2) you haven't posted your current data and coding attempt; (3) without that ... well, Stack Overflow is not a from-scratch coding service.

Comment: @Prune okay I've done my calculations in excel; and I got 84% accuracy for a, but that doesn't seem right since the overall successful classification is ~24%? Edited OP to include excel snippet